# How to say thank you for the ....?

Tags: sentence-construction

Consider below chronological events.

I sent an E-mail to a professor and asked him a question.
He answered my question. Now, I want to send him a message and say thank you ... .

---

I need a **short and formal** sentence implying a sense of being modest, but not **very modest**!. e.g.,  "I am not a special person and his contribution to my question illustrates his great benevolence"

---

I have written:

1. > Thanks for the time you considered for my question.
2. > Many thanks for the time you dedicated to my question.
3. > I appreciate you for including my question in your considerations.

---

Do the above sentences sound awkward ? If so, any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: I would say something like "Thank you for your time and assistance regarding...". *assistance* here refers to the professor's reply.

Comment: A general advice that I'd like to add : If it's an important person that you are thanking, please use "Thank you" instead of "Thanks". Just saying "Thanks" sounds like either you are too lazy or that you were in a hurry.

Answer (score 3):

Your second sentence is fine. The first and third are awkward (the first makes it sound like you're thanking him for considering his time and the third sounds like you're saying you appreciate him rather than what he did).

My suggestion is to briefly state how (or simply, that) the answer helped you and then thank him for his taking time to answer you. (As a teacher, what I appreciate more than my students thanking me is their being able to communicate to me what they learned from me. There's nothing more rewarding than knowing that your students learned from you!)

1. > Your answer illuminated the problem for me. Thank you for taking the
   >   time to answer my question.
2. > Your answer was clear and helpful. I appreciate your taking time to
   >       answer my question.